# r = r + 1 not working concatenate list while its an int?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, int

I have this function that creates an empty 2D list. getal X getal wide and high.
Though when i execute the code i get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       line 49, in
    bord = rooster(5, "<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
       line 38, in rooster
    r = r + 1
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

- r is a counter in this code that stands for rows of the board.
- k is also a counter that stands for columns of the board.
- reeks is a string that gets split into characters.

The goal of the code is to make the board getal X getal wide and then inserting all characters from 'reeks' into their own separate slot.

```
def rooster(getal, reeks):
    #vierkant = [['']*getal]* getal
    vierkant = [[0 for r in range(getal)] for k in range(getal)]
    r = 0
    k = 0
    reekslist = list(reeks)
    while r < getal:
        k = 0
        while k < getal:
            vierkant[r][k] = reekslist[k + r*getal]


            k += 1
        for r in vierkant:
            print(r)
        r = r + 1
bord = rooster(5, "<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
```

Comment: When you do `for r in vierkant`, `r` becomes whatever is in `vierkant`; in this case, lists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The error message says that `r` is a list; we can't reproduce teh result, since the code you posted fails to run in several ways.

Comment: why can you not run this code... @Prune

Comment: @Prune what's wrong huh?

Comment: At this time I posted that, there were syntax errors and no driver program.  I have since rescinded my down-vote and closure vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop before the increment to something like this:

```
for v in vierkant:
    print(v)
```

if you use r in the for loop above it get assigned to the new value which is a row in vierkant, which is a list.